# Can I ask about relations of similarity beween 2 or more specific languages?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question

To give a real example, I'd be interested in knowing more about whether the relation between "go" (movement) and "going to" (future marker) in the Enlish language is shared by the Italian language (where I can say things like *Abbiamo visto X, adesso andiamo ad analizzare Y*, which is almost literally *We've seen X, now we are going to analyze Y*, and has fundamentally the same meaning).

Comment: Spanish (_vamos a ver_) and French (_on va voir_) have the same construction. Dunno about the other Romance languages, but it could easily be a construction like the Romance infinitival future paradigms that came early in Latin.

Comment: This is quite tricky. For  example: Me voy ahora means: I'm going now. Notice how the simple present becomes continuous in English. The same is true for French: Je m'en vais maintenant: I'm leaving now. So, it's more complicated than it might seem at first glance. Adesso andiamo ad analizzare Y is Now, we're going to analyze Y OR We'll analyze Y now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of good questions that can be asked in relation to that example. Probably the easiest one is a [reference-request](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question, assuming that other linguists already have noted this parallelism and wrote some papers about it. The parallelism between typical English scientific jargon and the Italian construction also shouts out "literal translation" or even "calque", making it a valid question in the [translation](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag.

Just make sure to narrow down the focus of possible answers in order to avoid the closing reason "too broad".